# Is there a way to know if a bulk query result was truncated due to size limit?

Tags: limits, bulk-api

The documentation says that bulk queries' results are limited in size.  http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_asynch/Content/asynch_api_concepts_limits.htm

However I can't find any explanation on what happens when this limitation is reached. I suppose the result is simply truncated. Is there a way to be notified when we don't receive all the records matching the query?

The only solution I see is to perform two queries. One with only the Id field and the real query, then compare the number of records returned. This would take quite a long time and consume API calls.

I only want  to be informed automatically that I have to split the query.

Thank you

Comment: don't you get the results in a paged/bulk format?

Comment: Bulk queries return csv or xml files, and there is a limitation of 10 files of 1 gigabyte each. There is no information regarding how to know if the whole result fitted in the files or if it was truncated.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look at how you might be able to use limit class methods to accomplish what you desire.

Several calls that come to mind are: `getQueryLocatorRows` (Returns the number of records that have been returned by the Database.getQueryLocator method), `getQueryRows`(Returns the number of records that have been returned by issuing SOQL queries) and `getLimitQueryRows`(Returns the total number of records that can be returned by issuing SOQL queries).

I'd think that doing a comparison between `getLimitQueryRows` and `getQueryRows` (the actual number of lines returned) would tell you what you need to know. How to integrate them into your existing code is of course an entirely different issue. ;)